# ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotations StringLength On Password ModelState.IsValid Fails When Hashed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hash, data-annotations, modelstate

First question is, using StringLength, is it possible to specify only a minimum length? More importantly, this is what I have for a password.

```
private string password;
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 6)]
public string Password { get { return password; } set { HashPassword(value); } }
```

What I want is when the user enters the password that they can only enter a minimum of 6 and maximum of 15 characters for their password. The issue lies in my Controller because ModelState.IsValid fails due to the hashing generating a huge string exceeding 15 characters. How can I get around this?

Comment: Why don't you use 2 fields for entered password and for encrypted?

Or you can Hash password after passing `Model.IsValid` condition

Comment: Great idea, didn't even cross my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing your hashing elsewhere (e.g. in the controller) instead of doing it in the set accessor of the property.

Comment: Maybe a seperate "HashedPassword" property.